# How to make drop-down (NOT SHEET) windows in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I am wondering how to make a drop-down window like in iCal. Should I just use a borderless NSWindow and an NSView with a rounded-rect drawn in it? Or is there an apple-provided solution?

[image: screenshot]

Thanks.

Comment: That's called a pop-over. They first appeared in public API in Cocoa Touch; they're coming to Cocoa in Lion, according to one of the slides in the WWDC 2011 keynote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no Apple-provided solution. [MAAttachedWindow](http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass) is probably a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apple Sample Code [Animated Table View](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AnimatedTableView/Introduction/Intro.html), specifically `ATPopupWindow` and `ATBorderView`.