# How to draw a "speech bubble" above NSWindow?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Notice this app:

[image]

How can I draw that sort of triangle above an existing `NSWindow`? I know the app in question probably draws the whole thing as a custom window, but I want to keep the existing title bar.  Is there any way to draw a triangle and attach it above a `NSWindow`? Please note that the solution has to be MAS-compatible (i.e. no private frameworks or classes).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make drop-down (NOT SHEET) windows in cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542064/how-to-make-drop-down-not-sheet-windows-in-cocoa)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. The OP is asking whether it's possible to extend the window frame of an existing window without creating a custom window, this is different to the pop-up window in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to create a borderless child window with no shadow that overlays the edge of the existing window. You'd need to draw any shadow yourself.

Comment: I understand the concept, I just needed a little help drawing it.  I have drawn a bit on iOS, but on the Mac I'm new.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look into drawing on the Mac (the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290) is a good start).

Answer (score 0):

A more comprehensive solution would involve subclassing `NSThemeFrame` and doing some custom drawing. Take a look at Matt Gallagher's [Drawing a custom window on Mac OS X](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html). It contains a wealth of helpful information, and Google will also be of great help here.

Comment: Bear in mind that `NSThemeFrame` is a private class. No app store for you.

Comment: Aha.  Thanks for mentioning, Rob, this won't work for me.  It's gotta be AppStore-safe.

Comment: That's true (though you didn't originally mention it). Still, people who look back might find this worth noting. I hope you don't mind I added a MAS-compatibility note to your original question, so people don't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an open source (BSD) framework that draws windows similar to this: https://github.com/sbooth/SFBPopovers

It won't directly do what you need but will illustrate the basics of drawing custom window frames.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  I didn't really want the HUD-style window, I just wanted to keep my existing window style and add a little triangle above that. I've used your code in the past and it works quite well, it's just not what I'm needing right now.